# Flex-wrap only wraps one item in container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Situation**: I have a `div` with flex and `h1` and `h3` children inside it.

**Problem**: The `flex-wrap` does not apply correctly to the `h1` element.

**What I tried**: I have tried applying `width`, and `max-width` to the container but the `h1` tag doesn't wrap when resized but the `h3` does.
I've tried to apply `height` as well. I've applied the flex properties to other containers but no matter what the `h1` won't move.  The `h1` doesn't wrap to the other line. It just stays put and gets engulfed by the overflow when the browser resizes.

**Expected result**: the `h1` must wrap its letters when resizing the screen.

**Snippet**:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Francois One;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Francois One;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.v-header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.fullscreen-img-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-img-wrap img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header-overlay {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(250, 134, 188);
  opacity: 0.40;
  z-index: 1
}

.header-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-content h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Alfa Slab One;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
}

.header-content h3 {
  color: rgb(247, 45, 146);
}
```

```html
<header class="v-header container">
  <div class="fullscreen-img-wrap">
    <img src="giphy.gif" alt="audio waves">
  </div>
  <div class="header-overlay"></div>
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1 class="display-4">20Somethingandliving</h1>
    <h3>Podcast</h3>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without a working example - can you provide your HTML within a snippet in the question?

Comment: Would you mind also add a bit more of description about the issue? I can see properly wrapping when resizing.

Comment: What do you expect the text within the `h1` to do? How is it supposed to wrap (and when?) when it is a single word?

Comment: It's done it before with flex-wrap. I just can't seem to get it to do it again.

Comment: Thank you Ziad Darwich. This fixed the problem and answered my question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to break the word? because your h1 is missing the spaces, without telling the element to break the word it will overflow.

**Solution**:

```
    word-break: break-word;// or break-all;
```

**Working snippet**:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Francois One;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Francois One;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.v-header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.fullscreen-img-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-img-wrap img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header-overlay {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(250, 134, 188);
  opacity: 0.40;
  z-index: 1
}

.header-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-content h1 {
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Alfa Slab One;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
}

.header-content h3 {
  color: rgb(247, 45, 146);
}
```

```html
<header class="v-header container">
  <div class="fullscreen-img-wrap">
    <img src="giphy.gif" alt="audio waves">
  </div>
  <div class="header-overlay"></div>
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1 class="display-4">20Somethingandliving</h1>
    <h3>Podcast</h3>
  </div>
</header>
```